# Launch Virtual Machine with Static ip in softlayer using rest api

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need a solution how to launch Virtual machine with static ip in softlayer ,i search in many sites still i can't get any answer static ip is supported by softlayer and want know what is the way to order static ip in softlayer and also how to interfere with virtual machine

Advanced  thanks for your answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to order a virtual guest with any specification you should get the correct item price ids, for this you could run the next request:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/46/getItemPrices.json
Method: GET
```

Once you get the item price ids you can use them to verify/place an order with the characteristics that you want, here an example to order a VSI with static IPv4:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder.json
Method: POST
Body:
{
                "parameters": [
                                {
                                    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest",
                                    "quantity": 1,
                                    "virtualGuests": [
                                        {"hostname": "test-template", "domain": "example.com"}
                                    ],
                                    "location": 168642,
                                    "packageId": 46,
                                    "prices": [
                                        {"id": 1640},
                                        {"id": 1644},
                                        {"id":  905},  
                                        {"id":  272},  
                                        {"id":50231}, 
                                        {"id":   21},  
                                        {"id": 2202},  
                                        {"id":13945},  
                                        {"id":   55},  
                                        {"id":   57},  
                                        {"id":   58},  
                                        {"id":  420},  
                                        {"id":  418},
                                        {"id":   22}
                                    ]
                                }
                ]
}
```

Additionally you could use this python script which is documented and describes each item price id used in the REST request for static IPv4:
Note: The script uses the SL python client https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python

```
"""
Order Virtual Guest with Static IPv4.

Important manual pages:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

USERNAME = 'set me
API_KEY = 'set me

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

order = {
    'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest',
    'quantity': 1,
    'virtualGuests': [
        {'hostname': 'test-template', 'domain': 'example.com'}
    ],
    'location': 168642,  # San Jose 1
    'packageId': 46,     # CCI Package
    'prices': [
        {'id': 1640},  # 1 x 2.0 GHz Core
        {'id': 1644},  # 1 GB RAM
        {'id':  905},  # Reboot / Remote Console
        {'id':  272},  # 10 Mbps Public & Private Networks
        {'id':50231},  # 1000 GB Bandwidth
        {'id':   21},  # 1 IP Address
        {'id': 2202},  # 25 GB (SAN)
        {'id':13945},  # CentOS 6.x - Minimal Install (64 bit)
        {'id':   55},  # Host Ping Monitoring
        {'id':   57},  # Email and Ticket Notifications
        {'id':   58},  # Automated Notification Response
        {'id':  420},  # Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account
        {'id':  418},  # Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting
        {'id':   22}   # 4 Public IP Addresses
    ]
}

try:
    # Replace verifyOrder for placeOrder
    result = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order'].verifyOrder(order)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    pp('Unable to verify/place order faultCode=%s, faultString=%s' 
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Here an example to order a VSI with static IPv6:

```
https:// $username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder.json
Method: POST
Body:
{
                "parameters": [
                                {
                                    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest",
                                    "quantity": 1,
                                    "virtualGuests": [
                                        {"hostname": "test-template", "domain": "example.com"}
                                    ],
                                    "location": 168642,
                                    "packageId": 46,
                                    "prices": [
                                        {"id": 1640},
                                        {"id": 1644},
                                        {"id":  905},  
                                        {"id":  272},  
                                        {"id":50231}, 
                                        {"id":   21},  
                                        {"id": 2202},  
                                        {"id":13945},  
                                        {"id":   55},  
                                        {"id":   57},  
                                        {"id":   58},  
                                        {"id":  420},  
                                        {"id":  418},
                                        {"id":  17129},
                                        {"id":  1481}
                                    ]
                                }
                ]
}
```

Additionally you could use this python script which is documented and describes each item price id used in the REST request for static IPv6:
Note: The script uses the SL python client https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python

```
"""
Order Virtual Guest with Static IPv6.

Important manual pages:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

USERNAME = 'set me
API_KEY = 'set me

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

order = {
    'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest',
    'quantity': 1,
    'virtualGuests': [
        {'hostname': 'test-template', 'domain': 'example.com'}
    ],
    'location': 168642,  # San Jose 1
    'packageId': 46,     # CCI Package
    'prices': [
        {'id': 1640},  # 1 x 2.0 GHz Core
        {'id': 1644},  # 1 GB RAM
        {'id':  905},  # Reboot / Remote Console
        {'id':  272},  # 10 Mbps Public & Private Networks
        {'id':50231},  # 1000 GB Bandwidth
        {'id':   21},  # 1 IP Address
        {'id': 2202},  # 25 GB (SAN)
        {'id':13945},  # CentOS 6.x - Minimal Install (64 bit)
        {'id':   55},  # Host Ping Monitoring
        {'id':   57},  # Email and Ticket Notifications
        {'id':   58},  # Automated Notification Response
        {'id':  420},  # Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account
        {'id':  418},  # Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting
        {'id':17129},  # 1_IPV6_ADDRESS
        {'id': 1481}   # 64_BLOCK_STATIC_PUBLIC_IPV6_ADDRESSES    ]
}

try:
    # Replace verifyOrder for placeOrder
    result = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order'].verifyOrder(order)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    pp('Unable to verify/place order faultCode=%s, faultString=%s' 
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```